# What's the CentOS equivalent of ssh-keygen -E?

Tags: linux, ssh, centos

The ssh client is asking me if the fingerprint of a new server is okay. This fingerprint is sha256.

The ssh server can tell me its fingerprint with

```
ssh-keygen -l -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
```

However this is in md5 format.

The documentation for `ssh-keygen` says that this is the fix

```
ssh-keygen -l -E sha256 -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
```

However the `-E` option doesn't seem to be available on CentOS. I can compensate on the client with

```
ssh -o FingerprintHash=md5 user@newserver
```

However good practice dictates we eschew md5, and it would simplify the automation and workflow (testing in multiple environments/distributions) if I could handle this uniformly.

How can I get a sha256 fingerprint of the ssh key on CentOS?

Comment: Minor nitpick: SSH doesn't use SSL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version of OpenSSH packaged by CentOS is *way* too old for this feature.

The alternative is to use `sha256sum` directly, since the 'fingerprint' is just a hash of the raw key:

```
awk '{print $2}' foo.pub | base64 -d | sha256sum | xxd -p -r | base64
```

The MD5 hash could be obtained using:

```
awk '{print $2}' foo.pub | base64 -d | md5sum
```

---

Or, you could skip the whole 'fingerprint' and 'manual confirmation' step, and simply copy the actual public key into your `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. (Don't forget to add the IP address in front of it).

```
echo "192.168.1.2 $(cat foo.pub)" >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

That way the key will be pre-verified, so to say. This seems to be an easy method to automate.